# Confusing regarding rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have this query

`Vote.group(:photo_id).order('count_all desc').limit(10).count`

that fetches all the votes and groups them by their photo_id and totals up the votes for those ids. I would like to add another constraint to it to only grab the ones with a vote count greater than X. I know I have to add a .where function somewhere but I'm not entirely sure where to put it or how to add in the new constraint...

Comment: Is `count_all` a `Vote` column?

Comment: I'm not rails expert but that code seems kind of odd. I think order doesn't matter when you are just counting. Also I'm not sure, but the count might always be 10 because of the limit. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well the count will always be 10 unless there are less than 10 votes @semperfids. But you're right using count with limit is odd.

Comment: @max Right now it's pulling 10 records max and giving me an aggregate count of the votes by photo_id, sorted by most votes descending. I want to be able to say. Only pull these if the count of the aggregate votes for the photo are greater than X. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `having` (SQL keyword as well as Rails method):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-having

```
Vote.group(:photo_id).having('COUNT(*) > ?', x)…
```